# Hybris catalog cronjob sync is not working

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For the first time when we run the sync cronjob (product/content) sync, it runs properly and creates media dump in the admin tab.

from next time when we run it, it just shows successful but actually, sync does not happen.

When I go back and clear the media dump from the admin tab, it starts working and again creats media dump.

So every time I am forced to manually clear the media dump for making this sync job to work.

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CatalogVersionSyncJob** is designed to run only once with each instance. So if we create a sync job instance by ImpEx/HMC, it'll work for first time but in the second execution, it won't get any newly/modified items and no item will be synced. Which mean, the system needs a new instance for each sync execution!

If we execute catalog sync from Catalog Management Tool(HMC/backoffice), then each time, it internally creates a new instance of selected sync job. Hence, it's working.

To solve this, write the custom job which basically does the same thing as HMC/backoffice does internally. Like creates a new instance, assign sync job, and execute it.

For more information, refer [configure-catalog-sync-cronjob-Hybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/create-custom-catalog-sync-job-hybris.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue, and the workaround was to create another CronJob that would remove those media dumps before the sync runs.

At a high-level we have a CompositeCronJob that does two things (there are actually more, but I'll just say we have 2 for the sake of this issue) in sequence:

1. Remove the media dump from the Sync CronJob
2. Sync CronJob

Comment: Could u provide any samples, please?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig; syncJob(code)[unique = true][path-delimiter = !]; attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code), qualifier)[unique = true]; copyByValue;; $catalogVersionSyncJobProduct  ; Category:attributeX                                             ; true
```